# MariaDB ERROR 1048 GeomFromText returning as null

Tags: mariadb, geometry

I am trying to restore a databese from an old server onto a new server and my geomertry columns are not importing

example

```
UPDATE `property_floor` SET
`floorBounds` = ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT((115.823402 -32.064224),(115.823509 -32.079125),(115.843336 -32.064224)')
WHERE `floorID` = '1'
```

> Error in query (1048): Column 'floorBounds' cannot be null

I have tried it both with the SRID and without it. tried both `ST_GeomFromText` and `GeomFromText`

I am at a loss for what is wrong, Is this a bug? is my data malformed (looks good to me, but I could be having one of those blind moments) or has something changed?

`floorBounds` is of type multipoint and the data I am trying to import was exported from a functioning database.

mariaDB version `10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1`

I only just noticed that the old server WAS NOT using mariaDB but MySQL (ver `5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`) But it should still be compatible, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `property_floor` SET
`floorBounds` = ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(115.823402 -32.064224, 
                                            115.823509 -32.079125, 
                                            115.843336 -32.064224)')
WHERE `floorID` = '1'
```

[MULTIPOINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multipoint/)

Comment: On looking up the documentation for MySQL it appears it outputs with each pair in parenthesis's where as that is not valid in MariaDB, Thanks.